# sum of series in c++ using if Conditional

Tags: c++

am trying to solve the equation in c++ sum of series  and am getting the right result
but I just trying to use the if statement to get the same answer of this equation

but always am getting struggling with it

```
# include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        double x = 1;
        double som = 0;
    
        double lim_nbr = pow(10.0, -6);
        int n = 1;
        do{
            x = 1.0 / ((n*n*4.0 - 1) * n);
            som += x;
            n+=1;
        }while (x >= lim_nbr);
        double correctSum = 2.0*log(2.0) -1.0 ;
        cout << "Sum = " << som  << endl;
        cout << "Sumcorrect = " << correctSum << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say you are getting the correct result. I assume with the code above. If so, you need to also show the code you are trying that is not working.

Comment: am trying to make if statement  to rewrite the code getting the same result

Comment: am just trying to practic with if conditional

Answer (score 1):

In this case for you to calculate a loop shape using only `if`, an alternative is to use recursive functions, look at this example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double calc(double lim_nbr, double som, double x, int n)
{
    if(x >= lim_nbr || som == 0)
    {
        x = 1.0 / ((n*n*4.0 - 1) * n);
        som += x;
        n+=1;
        calc(lim_nbr, som, x, n);
    }
    else
    {
        return som;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double lim_nbr = pow(10.0, -6);
    /* Call the function with the initial values */
    double som =  calc(lim_nbr, 0, 1, 1);
    cout << "SumWithIf = " << som <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The result you are getting using the `do while`  loop is an approximation to the exact value that you are getting in `correctSum`. `correctSum` is the result obtained by adding the series upto infinte terms, however your `do while` loop calculates only up to a finite number of terms. Therefore the difference of the two values shows up as the error.

Comment: OP's question was about how to rewrite the `do while` loop into `if` statements. Plus the reason `correctSum` and `som` are different is because OP used `lim_nbr` as a limit, so it doesn't get the most precise answer. He could simply change `lim_nbr` to `0`, and it will be about the same as `correctSum`. Third none of the popular compilers would ever implement `log` as the sum of an infinite series. Maybe a partial sum of the first few terms, but definitely not to its infinite precision.